# Highcharts not visible in leaflet popup

Tags: leaflet, popup

I am using the plugin Leaflet DVF (https://github.com/humangeo/leaflet-dvf). It uses this code to bind a popup to a polygon and create a table inside it displaying its corresponding records (a row for each record) coming from a JS file.

This is the code for the popup:

```
                onEachRecord: function (layer,record) {
        var $html = $(L.HTMLUtils.buildTable(record));

        layer.bindPopup($html.wrap('<div/>').parent().html(),{
            minWidth: 600,
            maxWidth: 700
        });
    },
```

This is the file with the record information:

```
var NLpopdens =[
{
    "CODIGO": "01",
    "NAME": "10",
    "POPU": "635100",
    "AREA": "162.18",
    "Density": "Title<br/><img src='http://joshuafrazier.info/images/maptime.gif' alt='maptime logo gif' width='350px'/>"
},
{
    "CODIGO": "02",
    "NAME": "11",
    "POPU": "263500",
    "AREA": "227.11",
    "Density": "Title<br/><div id='container' style='width:200px; height:300px;'></div>"
},
```

I am able to run the popup with an image but not with a DIV inside it. Does anyone know how to solve this?

PS. The Console in the browser gives me the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13
>       at Object.a.error (highcharts.js:10)
>       at a.Chart.getContainer (highcharts.js:258)
>       at a.Chart.firstRender (highcharts.js:273)
>       at a.Chart.init (highcharts.js:249)
>       at a.Chart.getArgs (highcharts.js:248)
>       at new a.Chart (highcharts.js:247)
>       at Object.a.chart (highcharts.js:247)
>       at HTMLDocument. (conflictdata.html:679)
>       at c (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)

And the Highcharts code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'area'
},
title: {
    text: 'Area chart with negative values'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
},
credits: {
    enabled: false
},
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, -2, -3, 2, 1]
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, -2, 5]
}]
```

});

Answer (score -1):

Manuel, see my answer here:  https://github.com/humangeo/leaflet-dvf/issues/117.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Here you have answered a question using just a link to another site.  Links can change or disappear without warning, so please [edit] your answer here to include your proposed solution, using your link as a reference rather than an answer.  Link-only questions may be deleted.